# Unable to make use of PHP regex matches

Tags: php, regex, string

I have some PHP code that accepts an uploaded file from an HTML form then reads through it using regex to look for specific lines (in the case below, those with "Number" followed by an integer).

The regex matches the integers like I want it to, but of course they're returned as strings in $matches. I need to check if the integer is between 0 and 9 but I um unable to do this no matter what I try.

Using intval() or (int) to first convert the matches to integers always returns 0 even though the given string contains only integers. And using in_array to compare the integer to an array of 0-9 as strings always returns false as well for some reason. Here's the trouble code...

```
$myFile = file($myFileTmp, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$numLines = count($myFile) - 1;
$matches = array(); 
$nums = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9');
for ($i=0; $i < $numLines; $i++) {
    $line = trim($myFile[$i]);
    $numberMatch = preg_match('/Number(.*)/', $line, $matches);
    if ($numberMatch == 1 and ctype_space($matches[1]) == False) { // works up to here
       $number = trim($matches[1]); // string containing an integer only
       echo(intval($number)); // conversion doesn't work - returns 0 regardless
       if (in_array($number,$nums)) { // searching in array doesn't work - returns FALSE regardless
          $number = "0" . $number;
       }
    }
}
```

I've tried type checking, double quotes, single quotes, trimming whitespace, UTF8 encoding...what else could it possibly be? I'm about to give up on this app entirely, please save me.

Comment: You example code is incomplete as not reporoduceable. The input data (what you say is a file) is missing. Now, I don't want to say you should post your file here, but you need to provide an example that contains as little code and data as necessary to show your question. A good way to get this is to create a new example from scratch with as little code as necessary to show your problem. Not only is that a good way that you better understand your own code (and most often it already gives you the answer), but it also creates a much better question as it is more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

Use '===' for eq for example

```
if 1 == '1' then true;
if 1 === '1' false;
if 1 == true then true;
if 1 === true then false
```

You can show file?

Comment: You could perhaps use the long word for "eq" and explain what the difference between == and === is and why - in your opinion - makes a difference in context of this question.

Comment: eq i mind eqvivalent( I don't know how to right) .
`if (in_array($number,$nums))` this not right. in_array return search key. If key = 0 = false. `if(in_array($number,$nums))` not work because return 0 this key array, but for `if` 0 is false. Because use `if(in_array($number,$nums) !==  false)` this right construction

Comment: sory equals, and sory for my English.

Comment: good examples you give in your comment! and don't feel sorry, my english is not good, too. maybe some more practice. But in_array returns boolean only, not the key. that is possible with array_keys and using the search value. hth (hope that helps).

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, array_keys return key... This example thery bad.

Answer (score 0):

You write in your question that you're using a regular expression to look for the term "Number" followed by a single digit (0-9).

A regular expression for it would be:

```
/Number(\d)/
```

It will contain in the matching group 1 the number (digit) you're looking for.

The pattern you use:

```
/Number(.*)/
```

can contain anything (but a line-break) in the first matching group. It obviously is matching too much. You then have a problem filtering that too much retro-actively.

It normally works best to first look as precise as possible than to fiddle with too much noise afterwards.